# React/MERN stack app is throwing errors on state property read, but they are still rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, axios

This project is a MERN stack app using Mongoose and Axios.

Currently this code renders everything that I want it to, but when I check the console I see this error message 6 times for lines 79 and 97 under user messages:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'creatureId')

My App.jsx file from the client:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './App.scss';
import Userfront from "@userfront/react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { getUsers, addUser, updateUser } from './services/userServices';
import { getCreatures } from './services/creatureServices';

// initialize Userfront
Userfront.init("rbvqd5nd");

// initialize logout button
const LogoutButton = Userfront.build({ toolId: "rodmkm" });

// main app component
function App() {
  // sets user and userfront id state
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState([{ _id: 0, userfrontId: 0, name: "", avatarPath: "", experience: 0, creatureId: 0 }]);
  const [userfrontId, setUserfrontId] = useState(0);
  // sets player creature state
  const [playerCreature, setPlayerCreature] = useState([{ _id: 0, name: "", imgPath: "" }]);

  // calls authentication on load
  useEffect(() => {
    // checks for userfront authentication and redirects user if not authenticated
    const checkAuth = () => {
      if (!Userfront.accessToken()) {
        return (
          <Navigate
            to={{
              pathname: "/",
              state: { from: window.location },
            }}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // retrieves user data, generates new user if needed, and updates user state on load
    const loadAsyncDataUser = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await getUsers();
        setUserfrontId(Userfront.user.userId);
        const userData = data.filter(user => user.userfrontId === userfrontId);

        try {
          if (userfrontId !== userData && userfrontId !== 0) {
            const newUser = {
              userfrontId: userfrontId,
              name: Userfront.user.name,
              avatarPath: null,
              experience: 0,
              creatureId: null,
            }
            await addUser(newUser);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }

        const newUserData = data.filter(user => user.userfrontId === userfrontId);
        setPlayer(newUserData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    loadAsyncDataUser();
    // loads player creature data
    const loadAsyncDataPlayer = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await getCreatures();
        const playerCreatureData = data.filter(creature => creature._id === player[0].creatureId);
        setPlayerCreature(playerCreatureData);
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    loadAsyncDataPlayer();
    // generates random creature, updates player creature in database, and then updates player creature state
    const checkAsyncDataCreature = async () => {
      try {
        if (player[0].creatureId === null) {
          const { data } = await getCreatures();
          const randomCreature = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)]._id;
          updateUser(player[0]._id, { creatureId: randomCreature });
          setPlayerCreature(randomCreature);
        }
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    checkAsyncDataCreature();
  }, [player, userfrontId]);

  return (
    <>
      {/* nav */}
      <div>
        <LogoutButton />
      </div>

      {/* user details */}
      <div>
        {player.map((user) => (
          <div
            key={user._id}
          >
            {user.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      {/* player details */}
      <div>
        {playerCreature.map((creature) => (
          <div
            key={creature._id}
          >
            <img src={creature.imgPath} alt={creature.name} />
            {creature.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My schemas from the server:
models/creature.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const creatureSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    imgPath: { 
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("creature", creatureSchema);
```

models/user.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    userfrontId: {
        type: Number,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    avatarPath: {
        type: String,
    },
    experience: {
        type: Number,
    },
    creatureId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

I have tried using varying methods such as functional rendering, using constants to access state property indirectly, etc. and have had no success.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `setPlayer` is called which later sets `player` and then should provide a object in `player[0]` which has the property `creatureId`, as the error stated. You can check this best with the React Dev Tools as Browser Extension. I think the player isn't be found or correct assigned and therefore this error happens.

Comment: [
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": [
      {
        "_id": "61a2c262e89b69cf296c76df",
        "userfrontId": 1,
        "name": "Jesse",
        "avatarPath": null,
        "experience": 0,
        "creatureId": "619fe14576cc938733d9f695",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "subHooks": [],
    "hookSource": {
      "lineNumber": 93,
      "functionName": "App",
      "fileName": "http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js",
      "columnNumber": 85
    }
  }

Comment: I believe that is the player[0] state value taken from the dev environment using the extension you recommended. (I like the extension btw)

Comment: If you want my help, you have to answer properly with a description and steps to reproduce, not only a js array.

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry, new here and not used to everything sending on "enter" lol

Comment: You probably have to check your lifecycle on how things get executed. As we can see, creatureId is defined in the state, but you get the error that it's undefined. Probably the code gets executed before the state is set with the creatureId property.

Comment: This seems along the right lines of what I need to do. I've tried many different combinations of code, so I am kind of left only with lifecycle to blame, which I think would make sense since the program still technically functions and displays the user creature.